# Replication MongoDB & SQLServer

Tags: sql-server, mongodb, real-time, replicate, database

I need to create a connection between ##MongoDB## and ##SQL Server## where I want to replicate a subset of my Database from SQL Server into MongoDB. Can anyone suggest for feasibility of the same and how ?

Is there any open source tool for the real time replication of the same.

Comment: For PostgreSQL there is https://github.com/stripe/mosql but it's no longer maintained.